# Preventing XSS attacks in php

Tags: php, xss, validation

I have a website with form for user entry and it is getting XSS attacked by hackers daily. 
I remove those infected forms daily but because these attacks are persistent i want to know is there a way to sanitize user inputs using php.

the form of attack is like this

> sddsweesn , [url=http://nsslwlessw.com/]nsslwlessw[/url],
>   [link=http://google.com/]google[/link], http://yahoo.com/

I am using strip_tags(),htmlspecialchars(),stripslashes() to sanitize data from users but it seems its not working in the above cause. Is there a way to sanitize above XSS attack code

Comment: as for the first three, unless you've an interpreter that turns those commands into working urls, those are not threats. If you mean "I keep getting spammed as hell" that's another story, you need to act on them _before_ they could post (captchas for example, or any other more user-friendly approach)

Comment: That is not XSS but just spam.

Comment: @DamienPirsy I dont think its a spambot because user have to fill captcha to complete the form. According to my knowledge spambots cant answer captcha

Comment: No, they can :) Well, at least sometimes, and it depends on the captcha you're using, but captchas are not definetly 100% secure against spambots

Comment: silly captchas are  chicken to them

Comment: It is not an XSS anyway

Comment: @DamienPirsy Is there a way to prevent these spaming

Comment: You can add a field with a question that needs 'human thinking' , there are captchas (which are an image display of string) or you can do something like 'How much is 6 plus 2'. Depends on the level of the spam bot - it might not figure it out.